# How to refresh jqGrid search dialog with postData filters

Tags: jqgrid

I'm working with jqGrid, and so far everything is working great. But now I'm working on allowing users to be able to save their searches so that they can retrieve them later and/or apply them to different grids. The saving is actually proving to be the easy part. I can get the grid to filter based on specified postData filters, but the search dialog is not refreshing with the filter criteria. Here's a little test that I have:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager', {edit: false, add: false, del: false, refresh: false, searchtext: 'Search'}, {}, {}, {},
{
    multipleSearch: true,
    closeAfterSearch: true,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    searchOnEnter: true,
    Find: "Search",
    afterShowSearch: function ()
    {
       ...// code to create the save search buttons goes here

       $("#fbox_" + gridID + "_save").bind('click', function()
       {                    
           var filters = {"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"id","op":"eq","data":"2"}]};
           $('#grid').jqGrid('setGridParam',
           {
               postData: {'filters': filters}, search: true}).trigger('reloadGrid');
           }
     }
});
```

I have tried several things, but nothing seems to get the advanced search dialog to update.

As a side note...I do NOT have recreate Filter set to true. It seems there's a bug there somewhere...with recreate Filter set to true, when you apply a search, close the dialog, reopen the search dialog, hit "Reset", close the dialog, and then go back in, there are no options available. All I get are the "grouping" options (AND/OR). I tested this on some of Oleg's demos and the result was the same, so it's not just my code.

Comment: Hi Jay, I need to solve siimlar situation, can I contact to you? (email?) 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52221985/free-jqgrid-advanced-search-with-dynamic-templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting recreateFilter: true solved the display issues. However, it still had the issue where after you click the 'reset' button, close the search dialog, and then go back in to the search dialog, you only see the group operator drop-down ("AND/OR") and the '+' button next to it. I was able to solve this by triggering the click event on the '+' button

```
var tableRows = $('#fbox_grid > table').find('tr');

if (tableRows.length == 2)
{
    $('input[type="button"]').trigger('click');
}
```

Now everything works great.

Comment: Hi Jay, your solution may usefull to me, can I contact to you? (email?)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was a long search to find this option. To be clear, I just add that the `recreateFilter` it's an option to the search option: `{ multipleSearch: true, recreateFilter: true }`