# free JqGrid advanced search with dynamic templates

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I know there are similar questions, but I didn't find a solution.
I have a grid with several TEMPLATES in advanced search, now I want to change those templates depending on selection outside the grid, WHITOUT recreating the grid.
Example:

```
$myGrid.jqGrid({
    //(options here...)
    searching: {
        closeAfterReset: false,
        closeAfterSearch: false,
        searchOperators: true,
        multipleSearch: true,
        multipleGroup: true,
        tmplNames: ["Template 1"],
        tmplFilters: [templates.tmpl1]
    }
})
```

Outside the grid...

```
var templates = {
    tmpl1: {
        groupOp: "AND",
        rules: [{
            field: "subject",
            op: "cn",
            data: "Hello"
        }]
    },
    tmpl2: {
        groupOp: "OR",
        rules: [{
            field: "sender",
            op: "eq",
            data: "john@doe.com"
        }]
    },
    tmpl3: {
        groupOp: "AND",
        rules: [{
            field: "to",
            op: "eq",
            data: "mary@poppins.com"
        }]
    }
};

$("#selectTmpl").on("change", function() {
    var selectedTmpl = $(this).val();
    //(what to do here with selectedTmpl??)
})

<html...> 
<select id="selectTmpl">
    <option value="tmpl1">Template 1</option>
    <option value="tmpl2">Template 2</option>
    <option value="tmpl3">Template 3</option>
</select>
```

When I change the "selectTmpl", I want to refresh the grid search template with selected option. Is it possible?

EDIT: What I'm trying to do is something similar (related) to [How to refresh jqGrid search dialog with postData filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529277/how-to-refresh-jqgrid-search-dialog-with-postdata-filters#comment91439702_16529277)

Comment: Do you tried just update `searching.tmplFilters[0]` parameter of jqGrid? I mean something like `var p = $myGrid.jqGrid("getGridParam");`, which get the reference to internal object with all parameters and then to set `p,searching.tmplFilters[0]` to new value inside of `$("#selectTmpl").on("change", function() {...});`.

Comment: Thanks Oleg  I've just tried what you said, I'm getting and setting the grid param `p.searching.tmplFilters[0]`, no problem, but this seams to no effect on the Search Modal, which remains showing the initial template option. Maybe I am missing some trigger like "redraw" or something?

Comment: By the way, I would like to perform these changes with the Search Modal still open, I mean, not closing the modal if possible...

Comment: It sound strange, because Search dialog is Modal and `$("#selectTmpl").on("change", ...` will not work during the Search dialog is opened. In any way a working demo (in fsfiddle) could clear all questions. I'm not sure that I understand correctly, what you need to implement. Probably you will need to use `resetFilter` and `addFilter` methods of `jqFilter`. In the most scenarios the usage of template can be replaced to filling of `postData.filters`.

Comment: For this scenario I set the options modal:false, overlay:0 . I will try to share you a demo in jsfiddle...

Comment: Oleg, can you tell me where are those functions documented? "resetFilter" / "addFilter" , I need to test them, but I don't know how to use them

Comment: `resetFilter` and `addFilter` could be helpful to modify filters displayed in Search dialog *without* closing and reopening the dialog with new `postData.filters`. The code of the methods is very easy. See [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.15.5/js/grid.filter.js#L758-L762) and an example of usage [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.15.5/js/grid.formedit.js#L319-L329) (where `fid = "fbox_" + p.id` - `"fbox_"` + grid id).